# Reading Text Files - Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file, text

When I compile and run I am given a fatal error at the 'if' Statement. am I missing a line? or something. I got it working before but wasn't sure how.

```
@IBOutlet weak var TextView: UITextView!
var TextFromFile = String()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TextView.text = TextFromFile
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TextFile", ofType: "txt")

    if let content = String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {

        let lines : [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByString("/n")

        TextView.text = content
    }
```

Comment: your path maybe wrong and you are wrapping it. Check your TextFile

Comment: where have you added your TextFile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you made force unwrapping...this means path is possibly nil and you are attempt to use nil value... rather you should use let binding like..

```
  if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TextFile", ofType: "txt"){

        if let content = String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {

            let lines : [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

            TextView.text = content
        }
    }
```

> And please make sure that you have moved your text file `TextFile.txt` to your Xcode-project (Use drag'n'drop and check "Copy files if necessary")

Check out in your `Project Targets-> Build Phases -> copy build resources` .... Make sure your file is in build resources

Comment: May I ask @Bhavin why there is a `let let` twice?

Comment: ok, it's no longer giving me an error. But there is no text showing ..?

Comment: Instead of \n, use         var splitTextIntolinesArray:[String] = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())

Comment: the code you ctold me to change has an error of unresolved identifier 

`at the end ())`

Comment: Its working great now thanks for the help 

`if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TextFile", ofType: "txt"){
            var data = String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
                if let content = (data){
                    TextView.text = content
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Check During copy TextFile in your project also check "Add to targets" this will solve your nil problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "add to targets" ?

Comment: Remove your TextFile and drag and drop in Xcode at that time "Copy files if necessary" you will get "Add to targets" option.

Comment: oh yeah I did that, some text show but it displays the path as well... i only need the text ..

Comment: Ok at least you fixed nil issue..?